# Fastest command to open a docx protected file

Tags: python, performance, ms-word, password-protection

Actually to try to open very fast the same .docx protected by a password file while don't knowing the password, i am using those lines of code:

```
import comtypes.client
word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
word.Documents.Open(wordPathFile, False, True, None, 'the_pwd')
```

But I've noticed that this method is very slow and that it used a lot of the processor capabilities especially if i need to repeat this task a lot of time, and very fast.

So is there a better way to do this task? That means a way that first -and it is the most important- must be faster and after less processor consuming?
*Reminder: the task is to try to open very fast the same file .docx password protected file while don't knowing the password.*

Comment: I haven't used COM in years but I think `Word.Application` more or less opens word. If you can do a lot of opens on a single Word.Application, you may see a performance boost.

Comment: @tdelaney can you writte a full code exemple as i ve done in my question (i think it will be three lines) like this i ll be able to mark the topic as solved please? And of course it will help me a lot.

Comment: If you have to repeat the operation, do you have a list of docx files to work with? Or perhaps everything in a certain directory. Basically, if you have a list of files to work with, after CreateObject, iterate through those files in a list. I need a feel for how you get the filenames to write a good solution.

Comment: No it the same file that i open multiple time in a very long loop (like 1 million iterations) i just need the code lines to open this same file very fast

Comment: That's different than I expected. You have a single file that you open many times in a single program. The first question is, can you just keep it open? Or do you need to close and reopen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the other way i've found and that seems to be slightly faster:

```
import msoffcrypto

enc_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(open(wordPathFile, "rb"))  # try start msoffcrypto-tool as OfficeFile with file-name and read-access only
enc_file.load_key(password=pwd_test)  # if password required, take the generated
enc_file.decrypt(open("decrypted.docx", "wb"))  # if password correct, open new file with write-access and copy content in it
```

**In all the cases if someone know a faster way to do this task (that means to open very fast the same file .docx password protected file while don't knowing the password), even if this answer is marked as accepted i will be very happy to read it and to mark his answer as accepted.**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to open the same DOCX file many times in a single program. The call to create `Word.Application` can be expensive. Instead, you could open Word once, and use it many times. Since you want to save state (the application object), a small class may be the most convenient.

```
import comtypes.client
import threading

class DocxFile:

    """Allows for opening a single DOCX file many times from a single
    Word.Application.
    """

    def __init__(self, filename, pwd):
        """Create a document opener for filename"""
        self.word_app = None
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.filename = filename
        self.pwd = pwd
        
    def open_doc(self):
        """Open a new instance of the document. Caller is responsible for
        closing."""
        if not self.word_app:
            with self.lock:
                if not self.word_app:
                    self.word_app = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
        return word.Documents.Open(self.filename, False, True, None, self.pwd)

def main():
    doc_getter = DocxFile("my_doc.docx", "secret-dont-tell")
    for i in range(1_000_000):
        doc = doc_getter.open_doc()
        etc...
```

Comment: It is exactly this i want to (try to) open the same docx file many time the fastest i can! And this a very big amount of time.

Comment: If its a single password protected file, I'd think it should always work or always fail ... unless the file is also opened somwhere else. I'm not sure the best solution, maybe put the open in a loop and sleep then retry to see if the doc closes (or maybe print a warning so the user can fix it). Since I don't know enough about your situation, its only a guess!

Comment: I ve just seen more deeply your code. First thank for your help but your code isn't enough good for what i need. THe reason is that i am not sure that i know the password of the file each time i tried to poen the protected docx file

Comment: Yes it is a single pwd protected file, but not each time the password is the same